# Split out-of-order string in python

Tags: python, string, split

I'm reading text files which may look like this

```
file1.txt:
Header A
blab
iuyt
Header B
bkas
rtyu
Header C
asdf
```

```
file2.txt:
Header B
asdw
Header A
hufd
ousu
Header C
dfsn
```

At the end of the file might be a newline, space, or nothing at all. The headers are the same in all the files but may be ordered differently as above.

I would like to map this so that a = blab\niuyt for the first input or a = hufd\nousu for the second.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question. It sounds to me as though you want to take an input:

```
XABCDE
```

or, equivalently (at least as far as I can tell in your notation):

```
BCXADE
DEBCXA
```

and return a mapping like

```
{"x": "A", "b": "C", "d": "E"}
```

(which is one way of representing the name-value pairs).

Is that correct? If so:

```
# This is the input.
c = "XABCDE"

# This is a dictionary comprehension, one way
# of creating a set of key-value pairs.
{
    c[idx].lower(): c[idx + 1]      # Map the first element of each pair to the second.
    for idx in range(0, len(c), 2)  # Iterate over the pairs in the string. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm trying to do something completely different, which I clarified in the edit above.

In your input example, XA wouldn't necessarily be a two-character pair.

X, B, D would be headers in the dictionary. However, A, C, E would be a variable number of characters.

Comment: @Jeff—given the new information you've added to the question, I felt I should answer it in a separate response.

Answer (score 1):

The question's been edited materially since my original answer, so I'm adding a separate answer.

The OP's input is given as follows: there is a file `foo.txt` with the following contents:

```
Header A
blab
iuyt
Header B
bkas
rtyu
Header C
asdf
```

The OP's expected output is a dictionary mapping header *values* to the contents (not lines) following the header, i.e.:

```
{
    "A": "blab\niuyt",
    "B": "bkas\nrtyu",
    "C": "asdf"
}
```

Note the last trailing line delimiter (`\n`) before each new header should *not* be included.

One approach:

```
import re

from collections import defaultdict

# Given something like "Header A" with a trailing newline,
# this will match "A" under group "key". The header formats
# in the example are simple enough that you could fetch the
# value using _, group = line.split(" "), but this accomodates
# more complex formats. Note that this regular expression 
# assumes each header will be followed by AT LEAST ONE line
# of data in a file!
PATTERN = re.compile(r"^Header\s*(?P<key>.+)(\r\n|\r|\n)")

# Using defaultdict with an str constructor means we don't have to check 
# for key existence before attempting an append. Check the standard library
# documentation for more info:
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict
structured_output = defaultdict(str)

with open("txt", "r") as handle:
    last_match = None  # Track the second-last match we made.

    for line in handle:
        maybe_match = PATTERN.match(line)

        if maybe_match:  # We've matched a new header group. Strip the trailing newline from preceding, if any.
            # This is either (a) the FIRST header we're matching or (b) the n-th header.
            # In the first case, structured_output[key] returns "" (see defaultdict), and "".rstrip("\n")
            # is "". In the second case, we strip the last newline from the previous group (per the spec).
            group = (last_match or maybe_match).group("key")
            structured_output[group] = structured_output[group].rstrip()

            # Move the last_match "pointer" forward to the 
            # new header.
            last_match = maybe_match

        else:  # This is not a header, it's a line of data: append it.
            structured_output[last_match.group("key")] += line

    # Once we've run off the end of the file, we should still rstrip the _last_ group.
    structured_output[last_match.group("key")] = structured_output[last_match.group("key")].rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iterator:

```
it = iter(string1)
res = {c: next(it) for c in it}
```